# Why does it not change the background-color as it should do?

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a code which has to change the background-color of the page or later a div red if a value is negative or green if a value is positive.

I have a code which is calculating right and a css which get some manipulations from a PHP-file.

But my file doesn't change the background-color. And I don't understand why. Maybe anyone could help, eventually explain what went wrong?

First: 
table quotation last two rows of price are 32 and 30.

style.css.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","boerse");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN -1 * price ELSE price END) diff_value,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN -1 * price ELSE price END) /
             SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN 0 ELSE price END) * 100) diff_percent
  FROM
(
  SELECT id, stock_id, price, @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM quotations CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY date DESC
   LIMIT 2
) q");

//$chnge = mysqli_fetch_array($result))


  header('Content-type: text/css');

  if ($result>"0"){
    $background = "red";
    $color = "white";
  } elseif ($result<"0") {
    $background = "green";
    $color = "white";
  }
    else {
    $background = "white";
    $color = "black";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

body {
  background-color: <?=$background?>;
  color: <?=$color?>;
}
```

tiat2.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css.php">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#responsecontainer").load("getdata.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#responsecontainer").load('getdata.php?randval=2');
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="responsecontainer">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In fact page should be red because 32 > 30 and so (32 - 30) > 0, but it is green. But what went wrong?

Anyone who has an idea? Thanks to everyone who tries to help.

Comment: I don't see where you are passing any variable data into the SQL query.  Why would you expect the results to change?  Is there something else in the background that would cause the data in the table to change? Also, what are you expecting to happen with the output?  All it is going to do is output some CSS text within a div, not actually apply CSS to anything.

Comment: @MikeBrant - Hope I understand you right:
In my table quotations I have several entries. The sql above is calculating if the newest row is bigger or smaller than the second newest row. I thought $result would get the result and I can use it for the if-statement. 
But I think I didn't really understood your question, did I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but try using integers for `0` instead of strings:

```
  if ($result>0){
    $background = "red";
    $color = "white";
  } elseif ($result<0) {
    $background = "green";
    $color = "white";
  }
    else {
    $background = "white";
    $color = "black";
  }
```